# want to import exported xml file in wamp phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, php, xml, table

I have exported single table from wamp phpmyadmin as xml file for data verification and want to import it again into database as mysql table. Please give me guidance, how its possible?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the database name in the left-hand pane, then click on "import" at the top.

Select "XML" from the format dropdown, "Choose File" and pick the file from your filesystem, then hit "Go".

[image]